# Node.js, RoR ou PHP?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, node.js, back-end

Pessoal até agora eu só estudei front-end, mas quero agora quero fazer uma aplicação completa e para isso preciso de conhecimentos para programar o servidor.

Vejo várias opções de linguagens e frameworks e não sei diferenciar se todos eles servem para fazer a mesma coisa ou não.

Por exemplo: Posso fazer uma aplicação de upload de arquivos usando só um de cada? E um CMS? E geração de páginas dinâmicas?

Comment: Node.js que eu saiba é voltado para aplicações real-time (pense em chats e jogos multiplayer).

Comment: @Piovezan isso não é verdade. Por exemplo [o site do MooTools é feito em NodeJS](http://mootools.net/) e tem muita coisa interessante a correr no lado do servidor. E pode por exemplo usar a biblioteca que foi pensada para o JavaScript no lado do servidor (NodeJS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar várias coias.

PHP é uma opção, por exemplo, Wordpress é um CMS que utiliza PHP como back-end. Tudo isso que você está falando pode ser feito utilizando php, assim como outras linguagens, você pode usar vários tipos de linguagem não precisa ser uma só.

Aconselho você a pesquisar sobre esses frameworks (PHP, node.js e etc) para saber as vantagens e desvantagens de cada um deles e qual vai se adequar mais ao que você quer fazer.

Dê uma olhada aqui:

- http://nodejs.org/
- http://php.net/

Para mais informações sobre as linguagens.

Na minha opinião o PHP é o melhor, pois ele é simples de ser configurado e simples de programar. Pode ser adequado a tudo que diz respeito a sites e também interage com as tags diretamente. Sem falar na documentação que é bem completa e de fácil entendimento, a comunidade também é muto grande e muito prestativa, fácil de conseguir respostas.

O Node.js é muito recente, não quer dizer que não seja bom, mas pode não ser o que você está procurando.

Answer (score 1):

Eu escolheria PHP pela quantidade de documentação disponível na internet, exemplos e ferramentas para se trabalhar com ela. Node.js também e muito bom, mas como é relativamente novo, as informações ainda são poucas se comparado com PHP.

A [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/) é linda para se encontrar respostas. Leia ela e se familiarize com a linguagem.